# Does a creature constitute a solid body with respect to Dimension Door?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, teleportation

The spell *dimension door* reads (PHB, p. 221):

> If you arrive in in a place that is already occupied by a solid body, you and each creature travelling with you take 1d6 points of damage and are shunted to a random open place within 100 feet of the intended location.

1. Does "a solid body" include creatures?
2. If no, what happens if you suddenly share space with another creature?
3. What happens to the other travelers if only they and not the caster land in an occupied space?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes: a creature is a solid body

1. A creature would fit the dictionary definition of solid body. In context, the [spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm)'s wording appears intended to account for mediums (liquids, gasses, etc) that one could normally occupy. [Later versions](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm) of the Dimension Door rules are more explicit.
2. N/A
3. Although this is a DM call, the [spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm) says "*All creatures to be transported must be in contact with one another*", so one could surmise that they should arrive that way (even if that means that the whole group gets shunted to the nearest free space).

Comment: The only point I'm not sure is trying to use a Dimension Door spell to enter the area occupied by a creature 3 sizes larger than the characters that doesn't occupy the whole area (like gelatinous cube) since according to DMG pg.29 "a creature may move through an occupied square if it is three size categories or more larger than the occupant." Maybe it would be possible to (for whatever crazy reason you want to) teleport under a standing colossal red dragon with a party of medium characters.